# QListWidget - Removing Padding & Consistent Column Width

Tags: c++, qt

I created a QListWidget using setViewMode(QListView::ListMode) and setFlow(QListView::TopToBottom) to get this:

[image: screenshot]

The large space between the icon and the text looks odd so I tried to remove it with:

```
list->setStyleSheet("QListView::icon { padding-right: 0px; }");
```

and also:

```
list->setStyleSheet("QListView::icon { padding: 0px; }");
```

but neither removes the space.  Is there any way to remove the space between the icon and the text?

Also, you'll see from the above screenshot that QListWidget uses variable column widths, but I wanted all the columns to have the same width.  I tried this solution:

```
int width = 0;
int numItems = list->count();
QFontMetrics metrics(list->font());
for (int i = 0 ; i  < numItems ; ++i)
{
    if (metrics.boundingRect(list->item(i)->text()).width() > width)
        width = metrics.boundingRect(list->item(i)->text()).width();
}
list->setGridSize(QSize(width+30, 16));
```

However, it doesn't seem to work consistently and I had to use +30 to account for the icon area, which isn't a very good solution, particularly if the size of the icon changes.

Is there a better way to get all the columns the same width?

Comment: Have you tried setting your `QListWidgetItem`'s alignment to left?

Comment: The text is already aligned to the left.  The problem is that the 16px icon has padding on either side so it's actually 22px wide, which leaves a large gap between the text.  You can see it better in this screenshot where I've clicked on one of the icons to select it: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160615/ag99mdbt.png

Comment: The padding is, IIRC, fixed at six pixels for the `QWindowsVista` style. This is much the same as the padding between the icon and text on a pushbutton or `QLabel`.